# Does multi plane calibration calculate only Intrinsic matrix?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

Does Zhangs multiplane calibration calculate only intrinsic matrix? Does it calculate all the parameters of Calibration Matrix(both intrinsic and extrinsic)? Can anyone share quick math(not the original paper) behind how multi plane calibration calculates all the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember here is that each checkerboard defines its own world coordinate system. Zhang's calibration calculates the camera extrinsics relative to each of those world coordinate systems, i. e. the rotation and translation of the camera relative to each checkerboard.

Comment: Is extrinsic matrix not unique mapping from world coordinate system to camera coordinate system? Is there something like relative extrinsic matrix?